# Binding functions with reference parameters in Emscripten

Tags: c++, emscripten, webassembly

I have the following classes and want to bind A::getA and A::getPt. The only difference between this two functions is that one takes as parameter a reference to a int and the other a reference to the "Point" class.

```
#include <emscripten/bind.h>

using namespace emscripten;

class Point
{
  public:
    float x, y, z;
};

class A
{
  public:
    void getA(int &aa) const;
    void getPt(Point &pt) const;

  private:
    int m_a;
    Point m_pt;
};

void A::getA(int &a) const
{
    a = m_a;
}

void A::getPt(Point &pt) const
{
    pt = m_pt;
}

EMSCRIPTEN_BINDINGS(my_class_example) {
    class_<A>("A")
    .function("getA", & A::getA)
    .function("getPt", & A::getPt);
}
```

But when I compile, the binding to A::getPt is working but not for A::getA where I have the following error:

> non-const lvalue reference to type 'int' cannot bind to a temporary
>   of type 'int'
>                    internal::BindingType::fromWireType(args)...
>                    ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

Why is it working with a class but not a basic type?

Answer (score 0):

Because JavaScript don't have call by reference primitive arguments.

```
var a = 0;
object.getA(a);
// Always a === 0
```

Comment: So my only solution is to rewrite my code? Or is there another solution in embind for that specific case?

Comment: I think so, too.

Comment: Probaly you would not want to expose all of your code via embind. If this is an internal code and not exposed via public API, it will work correctly. Only your public Api should be exposed via embind - only that needs to be changed. You can always write a wrapper Api which doesnot take by reference and internally calls the byReference api.